# How to get json keys using angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json and I want to iterate and get the json keys: `Testing01`, `Testing02` and `Testing03` on my ng-repeat for my given json. How can I get it using ng-repeat ? Please let me know and thanks in advance.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/0gucxcq2/2/) is available.

Comment: have a look at this code ...

Comment: @dhana when you mark an answer you should give priority for the ones who answered fast, just for your information

Comment: @Sajeetharan, oh ok sure. Thanks You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="(key, data) in data.testingjson track by $index">
      <td> {{key}} </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <table>
       <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.testingjson">
          <td> {{key}}: {{value}} </td> 
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gucxcq2/6/

Answer (score 2):

Just do this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.testingjson">
          <td> {{key}}  </td> 
        </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/jkshs8pk/2/)**